# How to use @InjectMocks to inject dependency with same type?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a `User` class which has a constructor with two parameter of same type.

```
public class User {
    Dependency dependency1;
    Dependency dependency2;
    User(Dependency dependency1,Dependency dependency2){
        this.dependency1=dependency1;
        this.dependency2=dependency2;
    }
    public void test(){
        dependency1.print();
        dependency2.print();
    }
}
```

In my test, I have two Spy Dependency and I want them to be injected like `new User(dependency1,dependency2)`.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class InjectMocksTest {
    @InjectMocks
    User user;
    @Spy
    Dependency dependency1=new Dependency("dependent1");
    @Spy
    Dependency dependency2=new Dependency("dependent2");
    @Test
    void test(){
        user.test();
    }
}
```

But I find that dependency1 and dependency2 of `User` both refers to dependency1 in the test, like they are injected with `new User(dependency1,dependency1)`.

So how to achieve what I want with `@InjectMocks` annotation?

Comment: Why is it critical to use `@InjectMocks` instead of just calling `new`?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I know it's easy with `new`. But when it come to setter injection, @InjectMocks can inject dependency by the match of the property name and the mock name ,so I wander if there is some workaround to solve it when it comes to constructor injection.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you can trick Mockito into injecting the mocks using Field injection if you create the object itself first, and set the arguments to null. This works for me:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserTest {
  @InjectMocks
  User user = new User(null, null);

  @Spy
  Dependency dependency1 = new Dependency("dependent1");
  @Spy
  Dependency dependency2 = new Dependency("dependent2");

  @Test
  void test() {
    user.test();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
dependent1
dependent2
```

However, this behavior is not documented, so I am not sure I would depend upon it.

Comment: This is indeed a workaround but I think is no better than just use `new`. Anyway, thanks for you answer.